# Attempting to set HTTP expire header is crashing my site. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: http, header

I'm trying to set the the expires HTTP heater on Apache2 web server but every attempt I make either has no effect or crashes the site. I tried adding the expires header setting to my `VirtualHost` as shown below but this crashes the site. I don't understand why is this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/mydirectory
    <Directory /home/mydirectory/>
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript .now plus 1 months.
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript .now plus 1 months.
            ExpiresByType text/javascript .now plus 1 months.
            ExpiresByType text/css .now plus 1 months.
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days
    </Directory>
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
     <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried both of the following configurations for my httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule expires_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 7 days"

<Directory "/home/mydirectory">
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 day"
</Directory>
```

and

```
 LoadModule expires_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_expires.so
```

I can't get any combination of configurations to work for me. I've checked that mod_expires.so is in the correct location. Where am I going wrong?

I've changed my document root from `/var/www` to `/home/mydirectory`. This hasn't cause any problems before I tried to modify the HTTP header so I don't think it has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: What is "crashing your site"? What do the logs tell you?

Comment: Are your sure is the 19th line? It's more like the 22nd.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was solved by changing the word "one" with the numeral "1". "one" had worked on another site of mine. Perhaps it would work to change the numeral into a word.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days
```

on the 19th line is missing an `"` which maybe make your configuration corrupt?